# Joan Zapata PDF View swipe before rendered error

Tags: android, pdf, runtime-error, pdfviewer, vudroid

I've implement the Joan Zapata PDF View library into my project and when I load up a PDF document and interact with it before it is completely rendered I get a VuDriod error:

RuntimeError: error loading page

I have tried displaying a ProgressDialog that disables interaction until the onPageLoaded listener is called, but the document is still rendering after this has been triggered.

Does anyone have any suggestions? My next attempt will be adding a Timer to disable it until I "think" it should be rendered....

Answer (score 0):

This was a concurrency issue and I fixed it by adding 'synchronized' to the createPage() method in PdfPage under

```
org.vudroid.pdfdroid.codec.PdfPage
```

in the file system.

```
static synchronized PdfPage createPage(long dochandle, int pageno) {
    return new PdfPage(open(dochandle, pageno), dochandle);
}
```

This is where I found the solution: [here](https://code.google.com/p/vudroid/issues/detail?id=55)